# Deleting object without causing null

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which needs to traverse an incredibly complicated json file. This json file goes in and out of arrays and objects:

```
removeRecords(data, id)
  {
          let k;
          for (k of Object.keys(data)) {

              if ((data[k] != null))
              {
                  if ((data[k].hasOwnProperty('type')) && (data[k].hasOwnProperty('characterId')))
                  {
                      if ((data[k].type == "enableEscortingItem") || (data[k].type == "disableEscortingItem"))
                      {
                          if ((data[k].param1 == id))
                          {
                            delete data[k];
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      if ((typeof data[k] != 'string'))
                      {
                          this.removeRecords(data[k], id);
                      }
                  }
              }
         }
  }
```

But when I `delete` and it's removing an object from an array I get: `[null]` whereas I want `[]` (if it's the only object in the array of course). I'm aware the appropriate way would be to use splice, but I can't use that since I don't know whether I'll be in an array or not at that time. I've also tried using `.pop()` and `.shift()`.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem to get `null` after delete. Please make [mre]. You can get `undefined` after delete on array, but then you can use `flat()` to get rid of it.

Comment: Also Add sample data and say what is your goal, if you are trying to remove item from array, there are build in JS functions for that, like map or filter...

Comment: @ikiK thanks, might take me a while to make an example but I'll report back soon :) thanks so far

Comment: `since I don't know whether I'll be in an array or not at that time.` => `Array.isArray(data)` should be of help here

Answer (score -1):

Yes, when you delete an item from an array it is getting null instead of old value.
If you want replace null with something else use Array.map method.
If you want throw away element from the array - use Array.filter.
If you want to create completely new data type instead of you array (string, number, object etc) - use Array.reduce

Comment: Please show me how null is instead of old value. It is undefined. Not null. https://jsfiddle.net/ikiK_Cro/g1xptsa2/1/

Comment: do you use JSON.stringify() wrapper to check the changes?